# validation messages could not be displayed

Tags: java, struts2

I add the validating logic in the overloaded method valid in my action ExpenseManagerAction.java like below:

```
public void validate(){
    if (!StringUtil.matchDateString(expense.getTempDate())) {
        addFieldError("expense.tempDate","Date format is invalid");
    }
}
```

and my the content of the jsp is as following:

```
<s:form action="expenseManagerAction" method="post" theme="simple">
    <table width="80%" align="center" border="1" >
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">Expense ID</td>
            <td align="left">
                <s:textfield name="expense.expenseId" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PaymentItem</td>
            <td align="left">
                <s:textfield name="expense.paymentItem" />            
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Comments</td>
            <td align="left">
                <s:textarea name="expense.comments" rows="10" cols="30" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PaymentDate</td>
            <td align="left">
                <s:textfield name="expense.tempDate" cssClass="Wdate" /><!-- onClick="WdatePicker()" -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td align="left">
                <s:textfield name="expense.price" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td align="left">
                <s:textfield name="expense.quantity" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" width="100%">
                <p>Expert Search(Double click to magnify it)</p>
                <s:textarea onmouseover="showTooltip();" tooltip="Double click to magnify it" rows="1" cols="100" id="advanced" name="expertCondition" ondblclick="openExpertSearchWindow();"></s:textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <s:submit type="button" action="expenseManagerAction_smartSearch" value="smartSearch"  />

                <s:submit type="button" action="expenseManagerAction_reset" value = "Reset" />
                <s:submit type="button" id="btnExpSearch" action="expenseManagerAction_search" value = "Expert Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:form>
```

when I enter an invalid character "a" in the Payment date text box and click smartSearch button, I can see the the statement addFieldError("expense.tempDate", "Date format is invalid"); was executed when I debug it but the error message cannot be displayed on the form, I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

- Your `<s:form>` tag specifies `"simple"` theme.
- [Form element tags inherit the form tag's theme](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/selecting-themes.html).
- [The `"simple"` theme does not render field errors](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/simple-theme.html).

Options include:

- Overriding the theme on a per-field basis
- Not using the simple theme for the form
- Creating a custom theme
- Rendering field errors manually